# How to ask person to guess for something during conversation?

Tags: word-choice, nuances

I was conversing with my Japanese colleague:

> Me: Do you know how much a melon costs in my home country?
>      Colleague: I do not know.
>      Me: Take a guess.

I asked him how to say `take a guess`. He first told me to use `推測{すいそく}してみる`, but later retracted and told me to use `あててみる`. Which one is more natural in day to day conversation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think 当ててみて is more natural than 推測してみて in daily conversations. Maybe you could also say 'どのくらいだと思う？(か、言ってみて。)' or 'いくらくらいだと思う？(か、言ってみて。)'.

Comment: I often come across the situation where people ask "how old are you", and for fun I always say "take a guess". I use 推測して, for this. Is あててみて more appropriate in that circumstance as well? What are the nuances of 推測 that make it less desirable in conversation? Just too technical sounding?

Comment: @DaveMG-san, I'd say (さあ?+)当ててみてください(polite)/当ててみて(casual)/当ててごらん(to a child/your student/maybe someone younger than yourself), or (さあ?+)いくつだと思いますか?(polite)/いくつだと思う？(casual/to a child or your student)/さあ(orさて)、いくつでしょう?(half jokingly). We usually don't say 推測してみて in this situation, probably because the word 推測 sounds a bit too literary for a daily conversation.